# Count survey response in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to rails, I want to calculate the total number of responses for different options for each question. How to calculate the average for each question. These are my models. Thank you for your kind help.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :surveys 
end

class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy 
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many   :options, :dependent => :destroy         
  has_many   :answers, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question  
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :option   belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please update a expected result table mockup? Thanks

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: I want something like the following: assuming question1 has 2 options (Yes, No), yes : 50 responses and No: 10 responses. After this I want to calculate the average for each option for this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to create a field in your question class such as `responseCount:integer` and use `update` in your question controller to manipulate your data.

```
def update
  # update 'response' count
end
```

And once you finish, you can count the average by doing so:

```
@totalResponseCount = 0
@averageResponseCount = 0

for @question.each do  |question|
  totalResponseCount += question.responseCount
  averageResponseCount = totalResponseCount/Question.count
end
```